# How to add Arrow annotations with an offset to a bokeh plot with a datetime x-axis

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh

I want to draw an arrow or dots when 2 ma cross each other like there will up arrow when short ma cross above long ma etc. but I don't know how to plot when it is datetime. I try to use this code and it just give me errors.

```
#plot short ma and long ma
p.line(df['Date'], df['short_ma'], color='red')
p.line(df['Date'], df['long_ma'], color='black')

p.add_layout(Arrow(end=VeeHead(size=35), line_color="red",x_start=df['Date'], y_start=df['crossabove']+5, x_end=df['Date'], y_end=df['Date']))
#the crossabove + 5 so the arrow draw above where the cross occur
```

I post an image for the result i was expect       [the result i expect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKNj8.jpg)

code to plot candlestick chart and add arrow when 2 ema cross

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import timeit
import talib as tb
import datetime
import random
from bokeh.models import Arrow, NormalHead, OpenHead, VeeHead
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show

df =  pd.read_csv("D:/testdata/msft.csv") #open csv
df['short_ema'] = tb.EMA(df['Close'], 100) # short ema
df['long_ema'] = tb.EMA(df['Close'], 200)  #long ema
df = df.round(2)    #round to 2
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
#print(df.dtypes)
#chart figures
p = figure(plot_width=1400, plot_height=860,
           x_axis_type='datetime',)

#candle
inc = df.Close > df.Open
dec = df.Open > df.Close
w = 12*60*60*1000 # half day in ms
p.segment(df['Date'], df['High'], df.Date, df.Low, color="black")
p.vbar(df['Date'][inc], w, df.Open[inc], df.Close[inc], fill_color="#D5E1DD", line_color="black")
p.vbar(df['Date'][dec], w, df.Open[dec], df.Close[dec], fill_color="#F2583E", line_color="black")

#ma lines
p.line(df['Date'], df['short_ema'], color='red')
p.line(df['Date'], df['long_ema'], color='black')
                                     
#df.to_csv("D:/testdata/msft result.csv")

#loop for cross add arrow
match = df[((df.short_ema.shift(1) > df.long_ema.shift(1)) & (df.short_ema.shift(2)< df.long_ema.shift(2)))]

for x_, (y_, _) in match[['Date', 'long_ema']].iterrows():
    print(x_,y_)
    p.add_layout(Arrow(end=VeeHead(line_color="blue", line_width=4, fill_color='blue'),
                       line_color='blue', line_width=4,
                       x_start=df['Date'], y_start= y_ + 3,
                       x_end=df['Date'], y_end=y_ + 1))

show(p)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- For an `Arrow`, `x_start` and `x_end` must be a `datetime` format, not a `string` or a `dataframe`.

  - `x_start=pd.to_datetime('2010-10-09')`
  - The coordinates for the arrow may not be passed as a dataframe, they must be passed as individual values, which is done in a loop below.

    - `x_` is the date from the datetime index.
    - `y_` is the y intersection point, to which an offset (e.g. `+5`) may be added
- This [example](http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/annotations.html#box-annotations) was used, and [arrows](http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/annotations.html#arrows) were added to it
- See [Labels](http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/annotations.html#labels) for text annotations

```py
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.models import Arrow, NormalHead, OpenHead, VeeHead, Label
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.sampledata.glucose import data
from bokeh.io import output_notebook, curdoc  # output_file
output_notebook()

# for a file, uncomment the next line and output_file in the imports
# output_file("box_annotation.html", title="box_annotation.py example")

TOOLS = "pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset,save"

#reduce data size
data = data.loc['2010-10-06':'2010-10-13'].copy()

# test line to show where glucose and line cross each other
data['line'] = 170

# determine where the lines cross
match = data[data.glucose == data.line]

p = figure(x_axis_type="datetime", tools=TOOLS)

p.line(data.index.to_series(), data['glucose'], line_color="gray", line_width=1, legend_label="glucose")
p.line(data.index.to_series(), data['line'], line_color="purple", line_width=1, legend_label="line")

# add arrows to all spots where the lines are equal
for x_, (y_, _) in match[['glucose', 'line']].iterrows():
    
    p.add_layout(Arrow(end=VeeHead(line_color="blue", line_width=4, fill_color='blue'),
                       line_color='blue', line_width=4,
                       x_start=x_, y_start= y_ + 130,
                       x_end=x_, y_end=y_ + 5))

p.title.text = "Glucose Range"
p.xgrid[0].grid_line_color=None
p.ygrid[0].grid_line_alpha=0.5
p.xaxis.axis_label = 'Time'
p.yaxis.axis_label = 'Value'

show(p)
```

[image]

### Update

- In the following section:

  - `x_start=df['Date']` & `x_end=df['Date']` are used instead of `x_`, which should be a single date value, not a `Series` of dates.
  - The `for-loop` selects the incorrect values to be `x_` and `y_`. In my original `match`, the dates are in the index, but your `match` has dates in a column.

```py
match = df[((df.short_ema.shift(1) > df.long_ema.shift(1)) & (df.short_ema.shift(2)< df.long_ema.shift(2)))]

for x_, (y_, _) in match[['Date', 'long_ema']].iterrows():
    print(x_,y_)
    p.add_layout(Arrow(end=VeeHead(line_color="blue", line_width=4, fill_color='blue'),
                       line_color='blue', line_width=4,
                       x_start=df['Date'], y_start= y_ + 3,
                       x_end=df['Date'], y_end=y_ + 1))
```

#### Corrected Code

```py
for _, (x_, y_) in match[['Date', 'long_ema']].iterrows():
    print(x_,y_)
    p.add_layout(Arrow(end=VeeHead(line_color="blue", line_width=4, fill_color='blue'),
                       line_color='blue', line_width=4,
                       x_start=x_, y_start= y_ + 3,
                       x_end=x_, y_end=y_ + 1))

show(p)
```

[image]